# Enabling external interrupt on AVR

Tags: assembly, avr, atmelstudio

Attempting to enable the external interrupt on a ATmega328P via the following lines:

```
LDI R16, (1 << ISC00) | (1 << ISC01)
LDI R17, (1 << INT0)

STS EICRA, R16
STS EIMSK, R17

SEI
```

during my reset subroutine.

The idea is to have INT0 trigger a external interrupt upon a rising edge (i.e. from button press). The appropriate `JMP` instruction has been placed withing the interrupt vector table at `0x0002`.

During debugging in Atmel Studio 6 using the simulator, not only does no interrupt run when I toggle the INT0 pin, whilst manually stepping over instructions I found that the `EIMSK` register isn't being updated and that the instruction `STS EIMSK, R17` seems to be doing completely nothing despite R17 being set to 0x01 just prior execution of that instruction.

Quite a noob at AVR assembly, is this an issue with my code or something in atmel studio.

Comment: Bit rusty on AVR assembler but try changing `STS` to `OUT` and see how it goes.

Comment: @PeterJ On the ATmega328P the number of registers are greater than most AVRs such that the EIMSK register cannot be accessed by the `OUT` instruction so thats a no go for me (tried it anyway, studio threw an error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check also the following points:

- please reread the data sheet section "8.5 I/O Memory".  `EIMSK` lies in the address range that is supported by `OUT`. if you refer it via data store/load instructions you have to add some constant (0x20) to its address
- is the pin set as intput?
- is some pullup/pulldown present?
- have you defined some ISR?

additional to this i think its not a good idea to let a pushbutton trigger an interrupt, because pushbuttons bounce. so you get several dozens of interrupts per button push.

you should read about debouncing techniques and consider an timer interrupt driven readout of button state with software debouncing. 
if you understand german you may read http://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/Entprellung
this is a very good article and an efficient and nice implementation for debouncing of multiple keys.

### edit:

at 
http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=54896&start=0 this question is asked:

> some registers are both IO and memory mapped so neither 'OUT' and
>   'STS' generate a compiler error but only one works. How can this be
>   easily be determined?

two answers were given. one quite pragmatic approach:

> using IN/OUT by default and only LDS/STS on compiler error alway is correct

the other suggest using some asembler macros that distinguish between both cases (did not tested them):

```
; usage: InReg reg, addr
.macro InReg
    .if @1 < 0x40
        in @0, @1
    .elif ((@1 >= 0x60) && (@1 < SRAM_START))
        lds @0,@1
    .else
       .error "InReg: Invalid I/O register address"
    .endif
.endmacro

; usage: OutReg addr, reg
.macro OutReg
    .if @0 < 0x40
        out @0, @1
    .elif ((@0 >= 0x60) && (@0 < SRAM_START))
        sts @0,@1
    .else
       .error "OutReg: Invalid I/O register address"
    .endif
.endmacro
```

Comment: Its section 8.5, not 7.5. I thought the initial interrupt will cause the global interrupt flag to be cleared, disabling any further interrupts (thus solving the bouncing issue). And my apologies on the `OUT` instruction and `EIMSK`, I actually meant that `EICRA` cannot be reached by `OUT`. Anyway, even when using `OUT`, the simulator seems to not respond to that instruction.

Comment: @CPUTerminator pardon. its 8.5. i took a look to the atmega324 data sheet. but the avr core is nearly the same. you should use `OUT` for `EIMSK` and `STS` for `EICRA`. if you do so you should see that the register content has been changed.

Comment: @CPUTerminator regarding the bouncing: when entering the ISR the interupts are disabled but the flags still get set, so after leaving your ISR it will be triggered another time (if i remember correctly). besides that. the ISR will be triggered multiple times if the switch bounces longer than the ISR execution. According to the timing diagram on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce) switches may bounce several ms. No ISR should be run that long.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip. Turned out it was a glitch in Atmel Studio, reinstalled and the simulator "works" again (updating the appropriate register). Thanks for your help. Additionally: You should update the reference to section 7.5 in your answer just in case anyone comes across this with a similar issue.

Comment: What is the difference between `load`/`store` and `OUT`?

Comment: @sherrellbc In short: one uses IO mapped addresses and is fast the other uses memory addresses and is slower. But please read the referenced section in the data sheet.